# Using PFQuery to Query user input TextField and switch controllers if input matches a zip code in database (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, viewcontroller, pfquery

I'm trying to create a registration page with availability by Zip Code. For instance, a user can only register if the service is available in their area (zip code).

How can I go about checking the input text to see if it matches a zip code in my `Parse` database? So if the zip code the user entered matches one in the parse database I need a new `ViewController` called "Register" to open and the user can begin their signup/registration.

My current code, it works and it switches to the new view. But I can put anything in the ZipCode Field and it'll work, I don't want that to happen. The output is also "Successfully retrieved 0 Zip Codes".

My parse is pre-filled with a class called zipCodes and a field in the class `zipCodes` as well which contains over 20 of my `zipCodes`.

I'm just getting "error" in the Console when I type in a zip code that matches one in my database. This is what my database on parse looks like [i.imgur.com/OWRgC2K.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUsiM.png)

Here's the code:

```
class checkAvailability: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var zipCode: UITextField!
@IBAction func checkAvailBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    checkZip()
}

func checkZip() {
    var usersZipCode = zipCode.text
    var queryZip = PFQuery(className: "zipCode")
    queryZip.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects!.count > 0 {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) zip codes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("beginSignUp", sender:     self)
        } else {
                println("error")
            }
        }
    }
```